# Is Cloud Memorystore and FireStore a good combination for caching query results that I calculate?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-memorystore

I have a question.
I have a query that calculates aggregation data from Firestore (get all documents from user x after timestamp y with key z). Results in hundreds of docs.

Then I calculate a daily, a weekly, a monthly and a yearly value (AVG, SUM, MAX etc) from this dataset.
Result is an object:

```
{ "d": 100: { "sum": 100, "max": 23, "avg": 20 }, "w": .... , "m": { ....} ...}
```

I want to save this object, so I don't have to do the query and calculation every time again.

-Is it valuable to save this to Cloud Memorystore 
-The rate of recalculation of the same data is about 10-100 times per day that the user calls my service and this data needs to be present

No experience with Memorystore and its usages...

Comment: how much does your data in Firestore changes?  If caching data is a good option totally depends on this, and what will be more expensive either keep the cache or to do the calculation again, so could you share some more details please.

Comment: The data would change 5-10 Times a day, but I would need to get all data several times in between. Essentially it is incoming data from healthkit at which the app does aggregations and makes choices.

Comment: Where does the app that is consuming those values run?

Comment: IT runs in Appengine

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a good combination, you can use Keys with a limited time to live

One important thing to take in consideration is how much time you will give the values to stay alive on the Memorystore instance, as if it is too low then you won't be having cache hits, and if it's too high you might have incorrect values.

To explore more on this subject you can read this [article](https://redis.io/commands/expire) which talks about the key expiration time.

As you mention you are using App Engine take in consideration that if it's Standard you need to configure a VPC serverless Connector. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-standard) you can see the whole connection process.